# Cannot draw basic triangle with vbos opengl in lwjgl

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I tried to draw a simple triangle using lwjgl

Here is my 3D Object class:

```
public class ThreeDObject {
    
    float[] vertices;
    float[] color;
    
    int vao;
    int vvbo; //vertex vbo
    int cvbo; //color vbo
    int vtexNumber;
    boolean isSetUp = false;
    
    String fragmentShader;
    String vertexShader;
    int frag;
    int vert;
    int program;
    
    public ThreeDObject( float[] vertices, float[] color) {
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.color = color;
        this.vtexNumber = this.vertices.length / 3;
        setupVAO();
        this.vertexShader = defaultVert;
        this.fragmentShader = defaultFrag;
        setupShaders();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.vertices));
    }

    public void setupVAO() {
        
        FloatBuffer vb = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length);
        vb.put(vertices).flip();
        
        FloatBuffer cb = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(color.length);
        cb.put(color).flip();
        
        if(hasEBO()) {
            IntBuffer ob = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(order.length);
            ob.put(order).flip();
        }
        
        vao = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
        
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);
        
        vvbo = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vvbo);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        
        cvbo = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cvbo);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cb, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
        
        isSetUp = true;
    }
    
    public void setupShaders() {
        
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);
        
        program = GL20.glCreateProgram();
        vert = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        GL20.glShaderSource(vert, vertexShader);
        frag = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        GL20.glShaderSource(frag, fragmentShader);
        GL20.glCompileShader(vert);
        if(GL20.glGetShaderi(vert, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL20.GL_FALSE) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't comile vertex shader");
            System.out.println(GL30.glGetShaderInfoLog(vert));
        }
        GL20.glCompileShader(frag);
        if(GL20.glGetShaderi(frag, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL20.GL_FALSE) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't comile fragment shader");
            System.out.println(GL30.glGetShaderInfoLog(frag));
        }
        
        GL20.glAttachShader(program, vert);
        GL20.glAttachShader(program, frag);;
        
        GL20.glValidateProgram(program);
        if(GL20.glGetProgrami(program, GL20.GL_VALIDATE_STATUS) != GL20.GL_TRUE) {
            System.out.println("Can't validate shader");
            System.out.println(GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
        }
        
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
        
    }

    public void draw() {
        
        GL20.glUseProgram(program);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);
        
            GL15.glDrawArrays(GL15.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vtexNumber);
        
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
        
    }
    
}
```

And my constructor is:

```
t = new ThreeDObject(new float[] {
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f
        }, new float[] {
                1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
        });
```

(the constructor is wrong on purpose).

I removed some unused code, tell me if you can't find the error

All i get is an white triangle being drawn to the screen.

I tried every solution i could find if you can help me I will be greatful.

EDIT: I changed some code but still got the same result.

On the console i get this:

```
Can't validate shader

[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0]
```

Here's the vertex shader:

```
#version 330
out vec4 outColor;

layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 inColor;

void main() {

    gl_Position = vec4(inPosition,1.0);
    outColor = vec4(inColor, 1.0);

}
```

And here's the fragment shader:

```
  
#version 330

in vec3 outColor;

out vec4 finalColor;

void main() {

    finalColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);

}
```

the result is this triangle:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Gvv.png)

Result when i link the shader:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VeP1.png)

EDIT 2:

### I changed the code

I'm linking the shader now:

```
        GL20.glAttachShader(program, frag);
        
        GL20.glLinkProgram(program);
        if(GL20.glGetProgrami(program, GL20.GL_LINK_STATUS) != GL20.GL_TRUE) {
            System.out.println("Can't link shader");
            System.out.println(GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
        }
        
        GL20.glValidateProgram(program);
```

I also changed this line:

```
GL15.glDrawArrays(GL15.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vtexNumber);
        
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
        GL20.glUseProgram(0);
```

and changed the vertex and fragment shaders:

```
Vertex:

#version 330
out vec3 vertColor;

layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 inColor;

void main() {

    gl_Position = vec4(inPosition,1.0);
    vertColor = inColor;

}

Fragment:

#version 330

in vec3 vertColor;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main() {

    FragColor = vec4(vertColor,1.0);

}
```

but i still get weird results:

I get a black triangle covering half of the window, I try to move the camera but nothing changes.

[Black triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okeBo.png)

Comment: Why do you `glEnableClientState`? If you are using a shader program, you do not need the fixed function attributes.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I edit the post and the code to add more detail but I still get the same result.

Comment: Where do you link the shader program? ([`glLinkProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glLinkProgram.xhtml)). Furthermore, the 1st and 2nd vertex coordinate are identical.

Comment: @Rabbid76 when i link the shader i get an even weirder result: the screen is all red, I programmed for the screen to change color when I press a key, when i press that key nothing happens, the 1st and 2nd are the same on purpose, even when using a wrong triangle it still shows the same thing

Comment: When i link the shader using this: `GL20.glAttachShader(program, frag);
  
  GL20.glLinkProgram(program);
  if(GL20.GL_LINK_STATUS != GL20.GL_TRUE) {
   System.out.println("Can't link shader");
   System.out.println(GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
  }
  
  GL20.glValidateProgram(program);` i get the same result in the console and get this result in the window: The result is in the post

Comment: Actually i get nothing in the console, but the same red screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tested your code and found 2 errors,

**1.** As I suspected your vertex data for the triangle is arranged incorrectly,
When I test out your vertex data I got a blank screen (idk how you managed to get a triangle).

`t = new ThreeDObject(new float[] { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f }, // Your vertex data`

results in

[A blank screen (grey is the clear colour)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjQW7.png)

If you see, your vertex data is not arranged in counter-clockwise order (CCW); OpenGL prefers data in CCW order. It should be like this:

[Sorry for the link, cannot embed photo's yet, btw look at triangle 2, for counter-clockwise vertex order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzmo4.png)

So, I went an changed the order to this:

`t = new ThreeDObject(new float[] { -1.0f, 1.0f, 0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0f } //V1 --> V3 --> V2`

which resulted in:

[The triangle you hopefully wanted (with the colours)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdLn3.png)

[Here's another one (with a every coordinate halved)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXXwI.png)

**2.** Also this code:

```
    cvbo = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cvbo);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cb, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

should be like this:

```
    cvbo = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cvbo);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cb, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

Always allocate your attribute slots while the buffer is bound, so there is minial chance of mislocation error (a reason why you might got a black triangle, because your data was mixed up).

If you need any more help or need to see my code, please pop a comment!

Comment: Thank you for this reply, it actually worked, i don't know how i didn't realize that.

Comment: I also have another problem, the camera is not moving, I am using JOML: I create a matrix use the lookAt function (similar to glut) and setting as the projection matrix using glLoadMatrix, when i use the fixed function pipeline it works but not using vaos.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... Check to make sure your matrices do not have any errors; I tend to create the matrices myself so they can debugged easier than using OpenGL's built in functions. In a while, I will try to upload another answer on how correctly create the lookAt and projection matrix. :)

Answer (score 0):

TO ANYONE ELSE: This is not a answer to the question but to the comment of the author in another answer.

**ViewMatrix**:

When you define a camera, your are technically / need to already define a view space (therefore called `viewMatrix or lookAtMatrix`). This is important as this matrix transforms your objects from world space to view space (camera space), where all object are defined in terms of the camera.

(Think about it... if your `worldMatrix / modelMatrix` transforms all of your objects in terms of the world origin, your `viewMatrix` transforms all of your objects in terms of your camera (**where the camera is now the origin** and whatever is not seen by camera is automatically discarded).

This is how I define my camera class in my programs (Keeping scroll all the way till the end for a complete breakdown):

```
public class Camera {

private Vector3f position;
private Vector3f cameraDirection;

private float pitch = 0f;
private float yaw = -90.0f;
private float roll = 0f;

private float lastMX = 0f;
private float lastMY = 0f;
private float mouseSensitivity = 0.1f;

private Vector3f front = new Vector3f(0, 0 ,-1);
private Vector3f up = new Vector3f(0, 1, 0);

private Matrix4f lookAt;

public Camera(Vector3f position) {
    this.position = position;
    lookAt = new Matrix4f().lookAt(position, position.add(front), up);
}


public void input() {
    
    float xOffSet = (float) (Input.getMouseX()) - lastMX;
    float yOffSet = (float) (-Input.getMouseY()) + lastMY;
    
    lastMX = (float) Input.getMouseX();
    lastMY = (float) Input.getMouseY();
    
    yaw += (xOffSet *= mouseSensitivity);
    pitch += (yOffSet *= mouseSensitivity);
    
    if(pitch > 89.0f) pitch = 89.0f;
    if(pitch < -89.0f) pitch = -89.0f;
    
    float cameraSpeed = 2.5f * Window.getDeltaTime();
    
    if(Input.isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_W)) position.add(front.mul(cameraSpeed));
    if(Input.isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_S)) position.sub(front.mul(cameraSpeed));
    if(Input.isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_A)) position.sub(new Vector3f(front.cross(up)).normalize().mul(cameraSpeed));
    if(Input.isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_D)) position.add(new Vector3f(front.cross(up)).normalize().mul(cameraSpeed));
    
    position.y = 0.0f;
}


public void update() {
    
    input();
    
    setCameraDirection(new Vector3f((float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yaw)), 
                                    (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pitch)), 
                                    (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(yaw))));
    
    front = getCameraDirection().normalize();
    lookAt.identity().lookAt(position, new Vector3f(position).add(front), up); 
}

public Vector3f getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public float getPitch() {
    return pitch;
}

public float getYaw() {
    return yaw;
}

public float getRoll() {
    return roll;
}

public Vector3f getCameraDirection() {
    return cameraDirection;
}

public void setCameraDirection(Vector3f cameraDirection) {
    this.cameraDirection = cameraDirection;
}

public Matrix4f getLookAtMatrix() {
    return lookAt;
}


}
```

So, if you have seen the `lookAt` matrix is defined, using JOML, by three vectors:

A `Camera Position`;
A `Center (Front Vector + Camera Position)`;
And A `Up` vector;

The `Camera Position` simply defines the position of the camera in the world (*obviously how else would it exist*).

The `Center` is a little tricky to understand but all it does it defines the point to where the **camera should be looking towards**.

- If your center does not change, then you have got what is called a **`Third Person Camera`**, where the camera rotates at a variable radius **around** a `center` point.
- But if you want a **`First Person Camera`**, your `center` cannot stay constant, and therefore has to be recalculated every frame to be able to create a smooth, first person effect.
  If see above, in the `update()` method, the `front` vector is recalculated every frame using `cameraDirection`(the direction to where the camera is facing).
- The `cameraDirection` itself has to calculated every frame for the above process to work.
- PITCH, YAW, ROLL:
  [What are they](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTINR.png)

They are simply the rotations around the three axes `(x = Pitch, y = Yaw, z = Roll)` (see image). Using these and bit of Trigonometry we can calculate where the camera is looking towards (`cameraDirection`):

```
    public void update() {
    
    input();
    
    setCameraDirection(new Vector3f((float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yaw)), 
                                    (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pitch)), 
                                    (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(yaw))));
    
    front = getCameraDirection().normalize();
    lookAt.identity().lookAt(position, new Vector3f(position).add(front), up); 
    }
```

[We can calculate x and z components of the direction vector, using the y rotation (**YAW**) and some trigonometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJlKW.png)

[We also need the y direction, which can be calculate through the (**PITCH**)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVQBc.png)

**Make sure to normalize the direction vector (as with any direction vectors) to a unit vector, otherwise the center will be messed up**

So now we have got a `direction / front` and `position` vector.

The `UP` Vector:

To define a `"space"` like the `view space` or `world space` or `tangent space`, you need three vectors that define the three axes of that space --> **x axis, y axis and the z axis**

I do not know too much in depth about this (*and I might be wrong*):
The `UP` vector defines the **y axis** of the view space (the **x axis** is direction vector and **z axis** (right vector) is the cross product of the x and y axis).

The `UP` vector is just `(0, 1, 0)` and is never changed because the `1` represents that is point straight up (positive y-direction).

And there you have the `lookAt` matrix function:

```
                                //camPos     //center       //up
lookAt = new Matrix4f().lookAt(position, position.add(front), up);
```

Credits: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera,

definitely recommend looking at this tutorials for a in depth tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, call the `GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);` (for the colour buffer) before calling `GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);` (you should allocate your attributes before enabling the attribute arrays).

Secondly, your draw function incorrect:

When rendering,

1. Bind your shader (`GL20.glUseProgram(program)`)
2. Bind your VAO (`GL30.glBindVertexArray(VAO)`)
3. Setup your shader uniforms (I guess your not up to this step yet, so dont worry for now)
4. Enable your vertex attribute arrays (`GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(number)`) - Calling this method for every buffer slot allocated and EVERY TIME YOU RENDER (not just when you set up the buffers).
5. Render / call the draw function
6. Disable your vertex attribute arrays (`GL30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(number)`) - Calling this method for every buffer slot allocated and again, EVERY TIME YOU RENDER
7. Unbind VAO (`GL30.glBindVertexArray(0)`)
8. Unbind Shader (`GL20.glUseProgram(0)`)

Comment: Actually, I have to agree with @Rabbid76 here, even though your first and second vertices are same on purpose, this just affects your first triangle of the quad, your second triangle is still being rendered correctly, because the first two vertices do not affect it. (Thats why you have 1 coloured triangle and 1 black one (in your image) because the first triangle does not exist and cannot be coloured).

Comment: @SnipingPoodle there's only one triangle the second array is the color array

Comment: Also I am already doing what you're saying in you awnser

Comment: Wait hold on, I am just quickly gonna create a test program using your vertex data.